# Getting hidden div to appear when textarea has focus using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/mmtk7wzp/

For some reason, the code forces the 2nd textarea to have automatic focus, which I do *not* want.

I want the user to have to click into it for it to have focus. And when they do click, then the `HiddenDiv` should appear.

Any help appreciated.

```
<textarea></textarea><br><br>

<textarea id = "TextArea"></textarea><br><br>

<div id="HiddenBox"></div>
```

```css
#HiddenBox {
    background:red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:none;
}

#TextArea {
}
```

```
if ($('#TextArea').focus()) {
    $('#HiddenBox').fadeIn(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because your code runs on load and runs an if statement against the `focus()` method. This logic is incorrect as this will trigger the focus event and return a jQuery object, which means it will always equate to `true`.

To run some code when the `focus` event actually fires, you should hook to that event like this:

```
$('#TextArea').focus(function() {
    $('#HiddenBox').fadeIn(0);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mmtk7wzp/1/)

Note that you can use `show()`, `hide()` or `toggle()` instead of `fadeIn(0)`, depending on the exact behaviour you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with pure CSS with your current markup.

```css
#HiddenBox {
    display: none;
}
#TextArea:focus ~ #HiddenBox {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="TextArea"></textarea>

<br><br>

<div id="HiddenBox">*</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there's a thing. You need a handler for the in and out events.

I Wrote this and tried it in your jsFiddle. Replace it in the javascript box and it should work.

```
$("#TextArea").on("focusin", function(){
  $("#HiddenBox").fadeIn();
});

$("#TextArea").on("focusout", function(){
  $("#HiddenBox").fadeOut();
})
```

I'm not sure if this is what you we're looking for but i hope it works.

Regards.